# Ethereum events vuejs

Tags: vue.js, ethereum, metamask

in a vuejs app i am trying to connect to metamask. I can do this without problems, but I cannot get the events as specified here:

https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#events

How can I access this event?

```
ethereum.on('accountsChanged', handleAccountsChanged);
```

I state that in my forms I do this to recall the requests for ethereum:

```
const { ethereum } = window;
await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
```

I was also reading about EventEmitters, but I don’t know how to use them.

I hope I was clear enough, otherwise I apologize in advance.
Thank you